# Difference between GPU_0_bfc allocator and GPU_host_bfc allocoator in TensorFlow Timeline

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, tensorboard

When I try to profile the memory usage of model training in TensorFlow, I found there are two relevant information collected by TensorFlow Timeline tool, GPU_0_bfc and GPU_host_bfc (see the following figure), I am wondering which one can reflect the most accurate memory usage? or What is the difference between them? Thanks.

[Sample TensorFlow Timeline Profiling Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ll8pa.png)

Comment: I found this https://github.com/IBM/tensorflow-large-model-support/blob/master/README.md#increase-the-system-memory-gpu-host-memory-allocation

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `GPU_host_bfc` is the usage of the allocated memory on the host (e.g. the RAM next to the CPU). This is usually less than the physically (and/or through `swap`) available memory.
Further reading [here](https://github.com/IBM/tensorflow-large-model-support/blob/master/README.md#increase-the-system-memory-gpu-host-memory-allocation).